# Is there any definitive prevention for tooth decay?

Tags: dentistry, research, prevention, tooth-decay, enamel

I understand (in a too simplified way) that the main cause of tooth decay is the mineral breakdown of the tooth enamel by the action of acids formed from food debris on the mouth.

If that's correct, wouldn't be a definitive solution for tooth decay coating the tooth with a fine layer of some anti-adherent/non-stick element like Polytetrafluoroethylene on a long-term regular basis?

Is there some kind of research papers on this specific topic that i can read?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

There is no definite prevention. The teeth naturally weaken with age just like the rest of your body. However, smoking,   chewing tobacco, junk food, and drinking sugary drinks will not cause it immediately but definitely will speed it up and make is worst. Brushing your teeth and flossing them at least twice a day for each should help prevent tooth decay too. Unfortunately though, many people lose some of their teeth by the time they are in their 80s and may start showing signs of tooth decay as early as their 40s. You can only do what's most healthy and hope for the best.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/783/quality-of-references/784#784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta].

Comment: In particular, I don't think it's true that teeth weaken with age so that claim needs a source supporting it.